# JHipster is not showing version from pom

Tags: java, jhipster

I have a monolithic application generated with JHipster. After upgrading to `6.2.0` I can't see the version next to my app's name. When I print the value of `process.env`, I can see that the version's value is `UNKNOWN` and in my pom.xml I have `<version>1.0</version>`.

Why is it not showing the app's version?

Comment: I ran `mvn clean`, `./mvnw -Pprod` and then `npm start`

Comment: So, I ran `mvn clean` and then `./mvnw -Pprod` and it shows the correct value. Although this was working properly before 6.2.0, could this be a bug?

Comment: could you please post your answer to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your `pom.xml`, you'll see that the `APP_VERSION` env variable is passed by the frontend-maven-plugin to webpack which uses it to set `VERSION` in `webpack/webpack.common.js`. If `APP_VERSION` is not set, `VERSION` takes `UNKNOWN` as default value.

This can work only if the frontend build is run through maven.

It does not work if you build using only `npm start` because it overwrites `app.constants.js` without the env var set by maven. So as it is now it'll work only for production builds (i.e `mvnw -Pprod`)

This has been identified as a regression in JHipster: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/10192